# IntelliJ IDEA Live Template default value as last entered value?

Tags: templates, intellij-idea, live-templates

In IntelliJ IDEA, I'd like to create a Live Template that has a variable with a default value that updates to whatever the last thing I typed for that variable was.

For example, say I have the very simple template

```
$example$;
```

and the first time I use the template, I type "value".  Obviously the text that should appear is

```
value;
```

What I'd like to happen is that, the next time I use the template, "value" is already filled in for the variable $example$ (because the last time I used the template, the value of $example$ was "value").

Is there a way to get this to happen?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

IntelliJ IDEA doesn't have this functionality. One can probably create a plug-in that would remember the last used value and provide methods to save/restore this value for the live template functions via `groovyScript()`.

Comment: Hm, thanks.  Diving into the live-template-groovy-scripting process: How do you get a handle on what the user typed for a given variable?  (You mentioned "probably create a plug-in", what does that entail?)  What would be convenient is if there was a way to run the groovyScript(...) expression as the user completes the live template.

Comment: Please direct your plugin development and API questions [here](https://intellij-support.jetbrains.com/hc/en-us/community/topics/200366979-IntelliJ-IDEA-Open-API-and-Plugin-Development).